# Yocto glibc_2.30.bb fatal error: asm/unistd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: yocto, podman

I am trying to build Yocto Zeus in Podman and getting the below error. I noticed that sigcontext.h header file .recipe-sysroot/usr/include/ only has 32bit version whereas unistd.h file copied under asm-generic directory.

```
./recipe-sysroot/usr/include/asm/sigcontext-32.h
./recipe-sysroot/usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h


        | ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/syscall.h:24:10: fatal error: asm/unistd.h: No such file or directory
    |    24 | #include <asm/unistd.h>
    |       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    | compilation terminated.
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "../scripts/gen-as-const.py", line 120, in <module>
    |     main()
    |   File "../scripts/gen-as-const.py", line 116, in main
    |     consts = glibcextract.compute_c_consts(sym_data, args.cc)
    |   File "/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/git/scripts/glibcextract.py", line 62, in compute_c_consts
    |     subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    |     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    | subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7  --sysroot=/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/recipe-sysroot -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0=/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.30-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0=/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.30-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Werror -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fno-stack-protector -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -fmath-errno     -ftls-model=initial-exec      -I../include -I/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/csu  -I/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm  -I../sysdeps/arm/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/arm  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/arm/armv7  -I../sysdeps/arm/armv6t2  -I../sysdeps/arm/armv6  -I../sysdeps/arm/include -I../sysdeps/arm  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I. -nostdinc -isystem /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.2.0/include -isystem /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.2.0/include-fixed -isystem /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -DGEN_AS_CONST_HEADERS                  -MD -MP -MF /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/tcb-offsets.h.dT             -MT '/home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/tcb-offsets.h.d /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/tcb-offsets.h' -S -o /tmp/tmp2wx6srl6/test.s -x c - < /tmp/tmp2wx6srl6/test.c' returned non-zero exit status 1
    | make[2]: *** [../Makerules:271: /home/dev/inode_zeus/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.30-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/tcb-offsets.h] Error 1
    | make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    | In file included from ../signal/signal.h:291,
    |                  from ../include/signal.h:2,
    |                  from ../misc/sys/param.h:28,
    |                  from ../include/sys/param.h:1,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/generic/hp-timing-common.h:39,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/generic/hp-timing.h:25,
    |                  from ../nptl/descr.h:27,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/arm/nptl/tls.h:42,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/tls.h:23,
    |                  from ../include/link.h:51,
    |                  from ../include/dlfcn.h:4,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/generic/ldsodefs.h:32,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/arm/ldsodefs.h:38,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/gnu/ldsodefs.h:46,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ldsodefs.h:25,
    |                  from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/ldsodefs.h:22,
    |                  from <stdin>:2:
    | ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/sigcontext.h:30:11: fatal error: asm/sigcontext.h: No such file or directory
    |    30 | # include <asm/sigcontext.h>
    |       |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    | compilation terminated.
    
    |
    ERROR: Task (/home/dev/inode_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.30.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
    DEBUG: Teardown for bitbake-worker
    NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 437 tasks of which 430 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

    Summary: 1 task failed:
      /home/dev/inode_zeus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.30.bb:do_compile
```

Please note that I am able to build Jethro version using the Podman Container which runs Ubuntu16.04.

But, Zeus build is failing. Can someone tell me why these errors are seen?

Comment: After cleaning up linux-libc-headers and glibc, i again executed bitbake core-image-base again and build went through.

I am not sure why the recipe-sysroot not populated properly in the first time build itself.
          
        


        
  bitbake linux-libc-headers -c cleanall;
          bitbake glibc -c cleanall;
          bitbake core-image-base;

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by mapping the yocto build directory with host directory.

Yocto build worked liked a charm!

podman --storage-opt overlay.mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs --storage-opt overlay.mountopt=nodev,metacopy=on,noxattrs=1 run -it -v $PWD/my_yocto/build_output:/home/oibdev/yocto/build 4cbcb3842ed5